# Javascript : Form validation not working. Displays "not correct" message even if the value is correct

Tags: javascript, html

**The vaidation of a field in the form goes like this :**

1. Takes value from html
2. checks with expression
3. If false proceeds to next validation block
4. if true clears the field(i give .innerHTML="";)
5. displays a div i created that was hidden first, there is a OK button on the div popup
6. edit text on the popup div using .innerHTML to display my message(*eg."name is wrong"*)
7. click on ok Button
8. popup div closes
9. now i have to reenter the name correctly, none of the other fields are cleared.

Everything works just fine the first time, the problem is when i try to reenter the name correctly and then submit it still displays the popup div("name is wrong") as if i have entered the name incorrectly(*its like this for all fields btw not only name field*).

**HTML**

```
<div class="col_8 signup" id="s2">

            <!-- SIGN UP -->

            <h1>SIGN UP</h1>
            <form name="signup" method="post" onsubmit="return signup1()">
                <table id="tb">
                    <tr>
                        <th>First name</th>
                        <th>Second name</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="type your first name" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="sname" placeholder="type your second name" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>E-mail</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="email" placeholder="type your e-mail" id="email" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" placeholder="letters and numbers only" id="nuser" required></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Create a passsword</td>
                        <td>Re enter passsword</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="npass" placeholder="8 characters only" required>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="repass" placeholder="enter password again" required>
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <center>
                                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="log_btn" id="sub">
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <center>
                    <p>Already have an account? <a href="PROJECT_SIGNIN_PAGE.html">Log In</a></p>
                </center>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**Javscript**

```
// To close popup div
function ok() {
    document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'none';
}

// SIGNUP PAGE VALIDATION
function signup1() {

    // alert("success");

    let fn = document.getElementById('fname').value.toString();
    let sn = document.getElementById('sname').value.toString();
    let em = document.getElementById('email').value.toString();
    let nu = document.getElementById('nuser').value.toString();
    let np = document.getElementById('npass').value.toString();
    let rp = document.getElementById('repass').value.toString();
    let ex = /^[a-zA-Z]/;

    if (ex.test(fn)) { 
        console.log('Checking first name');
        document.getElementById('fname').value = "";
        document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "FName can only contain alphabets";
        return false;
    }

    if (ex.test(sn)) {
        console.log('Checking second name');
        document.getElementById('sname').value = "";
        document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "SName can only contain alphabets";
        return false;
    }

    if (nu.length >= 8 && nu.length <= 10) {
        if (expu.test(nu)) {
            document.getElementById('nuser').value = "";
            document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Username cannot contain symbols (except _ )";
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('nuser').value = "";
        document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Username should be 8 to 10 characters !";
        return false;
    }

    if (np.length >= 8 && np.length <= 10) {
        if (expp.test(ps)) {
            document.getElementById('npass').value = "";
            document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Password cannot contain symbols (except _ and @ )";
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('npass').value = "";
        document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Password should be 8 to 10 characters !";
        return false;
    }

    if (rp != np) {
        document.getElementById('repass').value = "";
        document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Please re_enter same password !";
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "SIGN UP SUCCESS !";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You are testing the inverse of what you should be testing with `if (ex.test(...))`. If `ex.test(fn)` returns true, it means that `fn` matches your regex, and thus contains a valid value. But in that case, you let it enter the if-branch as if there is an error. Change all the `if (ex.test(...))` to `if (!ex.test(...))`. (Also, your regex only checks if a string _starts_ with a single uppercase or lowercase letter. Is that correct?)

Comment: I'd also advice you to use more descriptive variable names. Shorter names don't make your code run faster and only make it harder to read it as humans. (As someone who read the code, I want to know what a variable represents. Having to backtrack what `nu` means makes it more difficult.)

Answer (score 0):

Most of these checks can be done without JavaScript nowadays, using the pattern-attribute. The error reporting is done by the browser itself (and corresponding with the user's language, which is very handy).

For example, your name check could look like this:

```
<input
type="text"
id="fname"
placeholder="type your first name"
pattern="^[A-Za-zÄäÖöÜüß]{1,32}$"
required>
```

Whereas in this example, the characters inside the []-brackets are allowed. The min/max-length is defined in the {}-brackets. The first value is the min. length, the second value is the max. length. Omitting the second value like this `[A-Za-zÄäÖöÜüß]{5,}` means "min. 5 characters, max. unlimited."

---

Oh, and one more thing:

You can even style the input fields according to their validity (based one the defined pattern), by using the pseudo-selectors :valid and :invalid. Example:

```
input:valid{border-color:green;}
input:invalid{border-color:red;}
```

Comment: Personally I'd not validate the first and last name at all. See [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @Ivar Yeah, thats also true. I just wanted to give him an easy example for the usage of the pattern-attribute.